# “href” value in HTML to open gmail app on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to open a gmail application instead of opening in chrome browser on button click or anchor tag click.

```
href="intent://example.com/#Intent;scheme=gm.ConversationListActivity;package=com.google.android.gm;S.browser_fallback_url=market://details?id=com.google.android.gm.ConversationListActivity;end;"
```

Comment: What if the device does not have Gmail? What if the user's profile does not include Gmail? What if the user has Gmail disabled? What if a non-Android user clicks this link?

Comment: This might work as well `googlegmail://`

Comment: Googlegmail:// is not working for me. We're you able to fix this ?

Answer (score 5):

If you add `href="mailto:example@email.com"` it should open the mail client on the device.